# How are the twist defects and domain walls on topological color code of pratical use?

Tags: topological-quantum-computing

I found an article that talks about the twist and domain walls on topological color codes, but I fail to understand how they are of practical use? Similarly, we can change the type of path and stuff like that but how are they useful?

Article: [The boundaries and twist defects of the color code and their
applications to topological quantum computation](https://quantum-journal.org/papers/q-2018-10-19-101/)

[image]